# Do I need to delete objects passed to google protocol buffer (protobuf)?

Tags: c++, memory-management, memory-leaks, protocol-buffers

I have simple messages:

```
message SmallValue {
    int32 val = 1;
}
message Value {
    int32 val1 = 1;
    int32 val2 = 2;
    SmallValue val3 = 3;
}
message SendMessage {
    int32 id = 1;
    oneof message {
        Value value= 2;
}
```

My piece of code:

```
// create new pointer for smallValue
SmallValue* smallValue = new SmallValue();
smallValue->set_val3(3);

// create new object value and set_allocated_val3
Value value;
value.set_val1(1);
value.set_val2(2);
value.set_allocated_val3(smallValue);

// create new object message and set_allocated_value
SendMessage message;
message.set_id(0);
message.set_allocated_value(&value);

// after some work, release value from message
message.release_value();
```

And my questions are:
1. After calling `message.release_value()` is it OK not to call `delete &value;` as I didn't create `new` pointer?
2. Will memory of `smallValue` will be deleted automatically along with `value` as I didn't call `value.release_smallValue();`?

// I'm a newbie to C++ as well as protobuf. Please do tell if something odd about my code.

Thanks!

Comment: I would be surprised if Google had a library that made memory management weird. I'd expect that you had to manage the memory yourself. That said, you only `delete` pointers that are allocated via `new`. `value` is not allocated via `new`; it is allocated on the stack. OTOH you should (almost) never have to explicitly type `new` or `delete`; you should use `std::unique_ptr` and `std::make_unique`

Comment: @Justin Thanks for the reference to the `std::unique_ptr` and `std::make_unique`. I'll be looking into it.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It is usually best to avoid using the `set_allocated_*` and `release_*` methods; those provide advanced memory-management features that you should not need unless you are really trying to optimize some performance-critical code.

You could rewrite your code like this to avoid having to worry about memory management as much:

```
SendMessage message;
message.set_id(0);
Value* value = message.mutable_value();
value->set_val1(1);
value->set_val2(2);
value->mutable_val3()->set_val(3);
```

Comment: Thanks for the advice! I will change to `mutable_*` instead of `new` and `set_allocated_*` but the `release_*` part is not mine to change. Which means `release_*` will be called after usage of message. Won't this cause memory leak as protobuf release ownership of pointer and I didn't delete it?

Comment: Yes, if you call release then you must delete the pointer yourself to avoid a memory leak. Maybe the code calling `release_value()` should actually be calling `clear_value()`?

Comment: Great point! It's actually is `clear_*` instead of `release_*`. Thanks a lot.